# Create "mydocuments" shortcut on desktop using powershell

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I'm trying to create a 'MyDocuments' shortcut on my local PC using the following script. But when I run the script through Azure Intune it creates a shortcut but the target is 'This PC'.

```
$ShortcutPath = "$env:Public\Desktop\Docu.lnk" 
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = [environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: does the account used have a `MyDocuments` dir? are there any errors? if you run the script using the same account that AZIntune uses, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You need admin rights to run this script, because you are reading other user profiles.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

$user = "YourUsername" # User to set link to desktop

# get user sid and profilepath

$sid         = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_useraccount -Filter "name = '$user'").SID
$profilePath = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID = '$sid'").LocalPath

if( $profilePath -ne $null ) {

    $currentUser = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current
    $currentSid  = $currentUser.Sid.Value

    # if another user load reg hive

    if( $currentSid -ne $sid ) {
        $pathReg = Resolve-Path "$profilePath\..\$user\NTUSER.DAT"
        reg load "HKU\$sid" $pathReg | Out-Null
    }

    New-PSDrive -Name 'HKUser' -PSProvider Registry -Root "HKEY_USERS" | Out-Null


    # get desktop folder of user

    $shellFolders  = Get-Item "HKUser:\$sid\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    $desktopFolder = $shellFolders.GetValue("Desktop")
    [void]$shellFolders.Close()
    [void]$shellFolders.Dispose()

    Remove-PSDrive -Name 'HKUser'

    # if another user unload reg hive

    if( $currentSid -ne $sid ) {
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        try {
            reg unload "HKU\$sid" | Out-Null
        }
        catch {}
    }

    # finally create shortcut

    if( $desktopFolder.Length -gt 0 ) {

        $ShortcutPath = $desktopFolder + '\Docu.lnk'
        $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = [environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
        [void]$Shortcut.Save()

    }
}
```